# Machine learning models don't work with continuous data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, logistic-regression

I'm attempting to get a machine learning model to predict a baseball players Batting Average based on their At Bats and Hits. Since:

```
Batting Average = Hits/At Bats
```

I would think this relationship would be relatively easier to discover. However, since Batting Average is float (i.e. 0.300), all the models I try return the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

I'm using sklearns models. I've tried LogisticRegression, RandomForestClassifier, LinearRegression. They all have the same problem.

From reading other StackOverflow posts on this error, I began doing this:

```
lab_enc = preproccessing.LabelEncoder()
y = pd.DataFrame(data=lab_enc.fit_transform(y))
```

Which seems to change values such as 0.227 to 136 which seems odd to me. Probably just because I don't quite understand what the transform is doing. I would, if possible, prefer just using the actual Batting Average values.

Is there a way to get the models I tried to work when predicting continuous values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve falls into the *regression* (i.e. numeric prediction) context, and it can certainly be dealt with ML algorithms.

> I'm using sklearns models. I've tried LogisticRegression, RandomForestClassifier, LinearRegression. They all have the same problem.

The first two algorithms you mention here (Logistic Regression and Random Forest Classifier) are for *classification* problems, and thus are **not** suitable for your (regression) setting (they expectedly produce the error you mention). Linear Regression however *is* suitable and it should work fine here.

Please, for starters, stick to Linear Regression, in order to convince yourself that it can indeed handle the problem; you can subsequently extend to other scikit-learn algorithms like RandomForest**Regressor** etc. If you face any issues, open a new question with the **specific** code & error(s)...

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I use LinearRegression I get this error: "ValueError: continuous is not supported". Same error applies to RandomForestRegressor.

Comment: @VirtuallyRealistic As I said, now that you have arguably narrow down the issue (i.e. you know that *some* of the models you have tried are indeed not suitable), please 1) accept the answer 2) open a new question with the details (the error you mention here is not even the same with the one you mention in the post)